# How to connect and call a matlab function from computer A to computer B

Tags: matlab, networking, model-view-controller

In my Matlab simulation I need to re-call a Matlab function running on another computer. For example: I am simulating a UAV in my computer, but the reference trajectory is in another Matlab program placed in another computer while these two computer are connected by Ethernet cable. Is there anybody could tell me how to do this recalling? any code for it?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Well, I guess you have to write a TCP/IP server in Matlab for this, for instance.

Comment: Can't you call the matlab script using a network drive?

Comment: Network Drive.?? what is this?